# AirPrint: restrict user to only print to printers that support TLS

Tags: ios, encryption, airprint

We are working on a secure application and one of the requirements is when the user prints the data is sent encrypted.

AirPrint seems to support TLS encryption but only on 'newer' printers. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/725/

There doesn't appear to be any obvious way to restrict our application to printing to these newer, secure printers. For example,  [UIPrinter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprinter) does not seem to reveal this information.

Is there a way to restrict this? The only even slightly relevant option I've found is that it appears a configuration profile can be used to restrict the whole device to printing to specific IP addresses, but this is quite a different concept to allowing printing to any encrypted printer.

Note: I am aware of the inherent insecurities around printing, however ensuring that the data does not pass over the network un-encrypted is still a worthwhile endeavor and one Apple generally seem supportive of.

Answer (score 1):

AirPrint API does not have an endpoint for JUST TLS printers.

Apple have a keynote on AirPrint security and what their recommendations/allowances are with security. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/725/

In short, TLS will be managed by the iOS itself. If TLS is available it will preference this and use it. Otherwise will fallback to NON-TLS.